# Does flash.now work in Ruby on Rails 3+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I am on Rails 3.0.3 and I am trying to render a 'new' action in my user controller with a flash notice I get the initial flash on the new user page, but also get a repeat of the flash message when I go to another page.
From the research I've done, you use `flash.now[:notice]` for renders but it isn't working.  Its not clearing the flash after showing it.

Here is my code:
users_controller.rb

```
def create
  flash.now[:notice] = "flash test."
  render :new
end
```

Comment: Do you have code in your application.html.erb or at the top of your view code to display the notice?

Comment: yep, I have the flash code to display on top of my view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will solve your problem, 
but did u try

```
flash.discard
```

Consider this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs)

Answer (score 0):

It should work, now has been around for a very long time.